# Version management of Debian package and auto update

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, debian

I have created a Debian package and now I want to release it somewhere and maintain versions and releases. Once every new release is thrown it should notify initially about the new version and auto-update.

Comment: I see intent and not a problem we can answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Release it somewhere*" is what distros do.

- See http://mentors.debian.net for how to get it into Debian. It will then flow downstream into Debian-based distros like Ubuntu.

"*Once every new release is thrown it should notify initially about the new version and auto-update*" is a problem. That happens to be quite the opposite of how Debian likes to handle new versions...

- In Debian-based systems, you *dist-upgrade* the entire OS and all applications at once (Ubuntu calls this a *release-upgrade*, like 20.04 to 20.10). There are very good reasons for this behavior: A uniform set of packages requires fewer volunteers to test and support.
- Many Debian Developers tend to be very much against unnecessary user notifications, unnecessary out-of-band upgrades, and third-party non-Debian self-upgraders. It's rather viewed as re-inventing your own wheel, but somewhat less round than the original. Be aware that a Debian maintainer might remove your auto-update feature so your application behaves as Debian users expect.

...but auto-updates are normal behavior for snap packages.

- Snap packages are not debs. A snap includes it's dependencies and auto-updates frequently (often without user notification). Snaps are distributed through the [snap store](http://snapcraft.io).